# Web components - Services / non html components

Tags: javascript, architecture, web-component

So I am coming from Angular and wanted to take a look at how to create `vanilla Web components`.

Now coming from Angular we tend to have things divided: Components (which acts as HTML,CSS, and some javascript) and then "services" which mainly acts do jobs such as collecting data and doing the "hard backend"  jobs that shouldn't happen in components.

now while I know that Web components and a Framework such as `Angular` are not the same things I am wondering how you would structure a project.

All the articles I've found on web components only explain the bare minimum (Shadow-dom, template and custom HTML)

They don't really show you how to create an enterprise-level application with the technology.

So my question is two-fold:

- What are the best practices for the structural architecture of an enterprise-level application made with web components?
- Is separation of core logic such as encryption, datastreaming, and so on something you do when using web components, and if so how?

Comment: "Vanilla Web Components" basically means custom HTML elements. [HTML Core Concepts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am more and more inclined to say **"Web Components" are a [language construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_construct)**.

It is called the **Custom Elements API**, so no different from the Fetch API, or the MutationObserver API

Then your question is: **How can I build an application with the [*name here*] API?**

#### Superduper "Tools"

Tools like Lit, Hybrids, HyperHTML, Lego, Stencil, all have a polyfill background, they made "Web Components" possible in the *olden* days when Browsers didn't fully support the Custom Elements API.
They have evolved to all claiming "*This is the best Tool to develop Web Components*"

In that sense they can be compared to jQuery.

Once a must for Web Developers,
and then selectors etc. became part of the W3C standard.
With the advent of IE9 **in 2011**, there was no real need for jQuery anymore.

#### Today's playing field

Now, Edge is running on Chromium, and Microsoft pushes Edge by default. All modern Browsers are up to par with the Custom Elements API

To take the jQuery comparison one step further back in history. There were dozens of jQuery alternatives 10 years ago. If you happened to invest in the "wrong" tool, you eventually had to convert to jQuery (or just Native JavaScript if IE9 was the oldest browser you had to support and you understood W3C standards (nearly) always win)

The same is going to happen with  Lit, Hybrids, HyperHTML, Lego, Stencil and all others.

#### The odd one out

Angular or Svelte or Vue all play 100% nicely with the Custom Elements API

React scores 71% at https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

The 60% React heads will say the W3C standard does not support React.

If you have been around long enough (> 20 years) you understand React can be compared to ECMAScript-4 (the W3C standard that [never made it](https://auth0.com/blog/the-real-story-behind-es4/))
Great technology, but if the Browser Vendors don't implement it in the Browser, it has no future. That means React is a potential *"jQuery"* also. Or maybe Flash (ActionScript had ES4 constructs) is a better comparison.

Makes for an interesting future:

- Will Facebook solve that 71% score?
- Will all Browser vendors (Mozilla,Google/Microsoft,Apple) implement React(Native)?

#### The Future is now

If you do not have to support IE11 there is a modern, level Custom Elements API playing field.

If you are learning, learn the API first, then see if Tools can make your development life easier (and accept the risk it all needs to be refactored when your tool of choice goes where MooTools, YUI and many others went) ...
Then again... banks still run Cobol... maybe React is the new Cobol?

#### Your questions

> What are the best practices for the structural architecture of an enterprise-level application made with web components?
> Is separation of core logic such as encryption, datastreaming, and so on something you do when using web components, and if so how?

You built applications *with* Web Components as you built applications *with* Classes or Proxies. Components encapsulate logic, only difference being the Custom Elements API **also** makes for great (really great) semantic HTML.

Alas, I see companies and developers focussing on the "Tools" instead of on the API

To me, a fool with a tool, is still a fool.

I was in the Microsoft SharePoint world, when TypeScript was launched.
Made good money refactoring MVPs "great" TypeScript (alas in ES3 syntax because they forgot to keep up with JavaScript) to ES6
I left that world when Microsoft went all-in on React.

Component developers now learn tools, like they learned jQuery...

#### Enough rambling

**The Custom Elements API is a JavaScript language construct.**

It does some things really well and others not so well.

Will the API make an impact? Yes, just like Classes and Array methods did. And those required a mind-set change also.

My advice:

- Play with them, like you learned `.map` and `.reduce`
- don't try to write full blown applications, start small
- create TicTacToe in a JSFiddle or CodePen.
- Ask [here on StackOverflow Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for feedback.
- make mistakes
- make more mistakes
- make more mistakes
- learn

The Custom Elements API is a W3C standard, supported by all Browsers,
this technology will work for as long as JavaScript runs in the Browser.

Comment: Really really nice answer thank you so much. Do you perhaps have some good links to articles that explain what you wrote in-depth?

Comment: I don't know any related articles (yet). As I said, nearly everyone is on the Tools bandwagon or comparing Custom Elements to Frameworks. I did [CardMeister](https://github.com/cardmeister/cardmeister.github.io) to show my own customers we have to think in Atoms (and Frameworks to construct the whole "Application") Haven't figured out all the terminology myself yet. Maybe we should say a Web Component is more like a Micro Service...

Comment: I second the comments re make mistakes and dearth of good articles. Every article I found missed, glossed over or assumed some concept that turned out to be important. The tools question could prove interesting. No sooner had I designed a few web components than I had a hierarchy of classes to cut down code duplication and provide a uniform way of doing things.

Comment: Yes, you will have created your own "tool" once you have programmed multiple components working together. Maybe the comparison to Lodash is apt, why learn "low-level" JavaScript if you can use Lodash. It all comes down to dependencies. My aha moment came when I dove into the jQuery source code for ``Object.assign`` functionality and learned I was loading bloated code 85% of which my applications never used. But I do eat soup from a can.. sometimes.. even though making my own soup from scratch is more satisfying... I still need/use Lodash for Curry recipes :-)

Comment: Another "problem" is Web Development has become a Programmers job. 20 years ago  HTML and CSS Developers without programming skills could maintain websites. The current mind-set is JSX and CSS-in-JS is the coolest thing on earth. Nobody complains when Lit-HTML is said to be MVC even though HTML and CSS are now string literals only programmers can change and built. But that is probably my weird view [pun intended] that MVC also means other skilled people should be able to work on a project,  like interior designers in a house renovation. Designers change Views! Hail Semantic HTML and Templates

Answer (score 0):

I gone through the same cycle and had the same question, actually in the position of the need to create an enterprise app and give my co-workers advise as a solution architect. With 20 years background in Web technology I thought it's not so hard to answer.
With the decision to support "modern browsers" the choice of the Web Component API was easy. I have also strong knowledge of Angular and React. We decided to use the project structure and similar tool chain (WebPack, Jest, you name it). This was clearly very wise.
In the beginning it was just a bit of library code we wrote to DRY. It ended after a year with a full blown thin library (let me [put it here as a reference](https://github.com/joergkrause/nyaf)). After some time we understood that we really need data binding, a state model, and integrated validation. You're simply not productive enough without. It's still a lot more compact than the fat frameworks, but it's a lot more than just a new kind of jQuery. Web components itself are just API calls. But everything else is hard work on top of Proxy and his colleagues. That's what all the smaller libraries try to achieve more or less (Lit, Hybrids, HyperHTML, Lego, Stencil, ...). We ended up with something really complete and very close to the fat brothers, but still very small (decorators like Angular mixed with JSX like React). But despite the fact that you're eager to write a library I'd recommend to look at one of the mentioned ones. Be aware that a future API may reduce the need further, I'm pretty sure ES2025 will have a great deal of that stuff on board.

> **Disclaimer**: I'm the creator and maintainer of such a thin library, called [@nyaf](https://nyaf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).