# Is it really necessary to make and use new custom elements and web components (HTML tags)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, web-component

I'm currently learning Front-end web development and the difference between Vanilla JavaScript, frameworks and libraries (React for example).
Now I'm familiar with web components for making new custom HTML tags. As I know, React is made for the same purpose, but when I visited the Instagram website (the first website that uses React that comes to mind) and looked at the HTML code, I didn't find any custom HTML element, in fact, most of the elements are made of "div"s tags.
If a complex social media website like Instagram isn't made of custom elements, then who uses them and why?

Comment: Thank you! this explains a lot.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284281/web-components-services-non-html-components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React is a totally different beast, dating back almost a decade. It was developed by Facebook because TOO many teams were doing TOO many updates in the same **DOM**. So they came up with a ***virtual*** DOM where all required DOM updates are merged before writing to the Browser **DOM**.

Works great for Facebook. Newer technologies like the Custom Elements API and Svelte (Compile, don't Transpile) have proven it is no longer the best solution.

Reacts outdated technology now scores a **meager 71%** on https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

#### React and W3C Custom Elements are not friends

Because the Green DOM elements are not tracked by React.

And if you want to mix Green and Yellow you have to basically re-write/wrap each and every component into React syntax. Because React not only does DOM Elements **diff**erent, but also does DOM Events **diff**erent.

[image]

#### The future

This makes an interesting future: **React and the W3C standard are diverging**.

And the W3C standard is defacto set by Browser vendors,
not by the W3C, as we learned from the never implemented [ECMAScript 4](https://auth0.com/blog/the-real-story-behind-es4/) saga (1999 - 2008)

So its

> Apple (Safari) + Mozilla (FireFox) + Google/Microsoft (Chromium/Chredge)
> versus
> Facebook (No browser!)

'problem' with the W3C is all members have to agree on a standard; that is why it took years for the Custom Elements API to mature... and React got a head start

Facebook does now *"own"* 60% of the developers market...
but hey,
Microsoft had 90% of the Browser market... **once**,
and Flash was installed on nearly every device....**once**

**The Custom Elements `API` will exist for as long as ECMAScript runs in the browser**

It is not a framework or library! It is a language construct.
Not learning Custom Elements is like saying:

> *I am not learning Set or Map, I can do everything with Arrays*

Older rant at: [Web components - Services / non html components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284281/web-components-services-non-html-components)

#### Or believe the 2020 Front-End Survey:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll go more in depth with the concepts.

Comment: Don't. You will become an old whiner like me, coughing up history lessons to predict the future. If you want an income, and don't care what you do, stick with React and Angular and Vue for another 2 or 3 years or so. If you want to prepare for **A** future, spend a week playing with Svelte. And learn Custom Elements stuff just like you learn what an Array or WeakMap is. It is a (javascript) language construct.

Comment: "The Custom Elements API will exist for a long time.", to be clear it will exists as long as ecmascript exists since one of the main policy is not to break the web, which means to be retrocompatible ad vitam eternam

Comment: Yes, that is why I am placing my bet on Custom Elements, and have stopped doing React projects. But... to be complete; Apple still refuses to implement *Customized Built-In Elements* (Safari can only extend from HTMLElement) So "standard" doesn't mean it will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, instagram uses [`react`](https://reactjs.org/) which doesn't transpile to web components

`react` is not the only components based lib to NOT use web components, there's also ¹ : [`vue.js`](https://fr.vuejs.org/), [`Polymer`](https://www.polymer-project.org/).

But some other components based lib do use web components as their base ¹ : [`slim.js`](https://slimjs.com), [`stencil`](https://stenciljs.com/).

All of these libs can be used with webcomponents, some even tell us how to do: [react](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html), [vuejs](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/05/21/vue-js-web-component/).

---

**!!! this part may be considered as opinion based !!!**

AFAIK the lib which chose not to use webcomponents were created before the web components API was finalized, and the cost to rewrite using them is too big.

---

**!!! this part is opinion based !!!**

Most person uses lib because web components doesn't give the same effortless two way binding.

In opposition webcomponents seem to give more control about when the component reload and how the binding is done, but it needs to be coded which is extra work.

---

¹ *based on the list of custom elements returned by [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321926/10153945) on the main page of each lib*

Comment: Well this is a very good point to consider, especially because not all browsers support web components and shadow DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In React it's different.
Working with React you are using **JSX**.
This is just tag syntax, which is neither a string nor HTML.
Under the hood this syntax in converting to usual JavaScript(using **[Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/)**).
You can read more about it **[here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)**.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect that React will convert the code.